# How to post on facebook feed my data?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webforms

I want to post on facebook feed (/me/feed).
Code on C# (WebForms):

```
string access_token = "**********";
var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.title = "Title test";
parameters.name = "Title test";
parameters.message = "facebookText...";
parameters.picture = "http://url_to_image";
parameters.link = "link to my site";
client.Post("/me/feed", parameters);
```

This code works, but there are ONLY "message - "facebookText..." and Content ('Title', 'Description' and 'Image' from meta tags of my site by the site link 'parameters.link') on facebook feed after posting the post.

How to post on my feed my dynamic fields data: parameters.title or parameters.name and parameters.picture?

There are not these data: picture(parameters.picture), and title or name (parameters.title), on the facebook wall after posting on the feed.

Comment: You can not specify these values dynamically at run-time any more, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations Facebook will take all this information from the Open Graph meta tags the URL you supplied as `link` returns.

Comment: All the data for the post gets dynamically from the database: the name of the post, the text of the post, the link to the post picture. But the main link should be redirected to the main company website. Can I do it with Open Graph meta?

Comment: You will need an individual URL for each unique combination of title, description and thumbnail you want to share. You can easily redirect human visitors following the links to those URLs elsewhere via JavaScript.